# Jquery Maphighlight how to change the part of the background

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I find this on  www.booking.com  and I wanna copy it.
 So I get maphilight to my projects.

But I don't know how to change the different background while mouse over/click

While click,the part selected change to yellow one of itself.

While mouse over,then get blue one.

The last image is what I implement.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with an [imagemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map), check out this two imagemap libraries:

- http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/
- http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/

If your source image is an SVG image with the zones in it, like the ones you tipically find on [wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aCalifornia_counties_outline_map.svg), you can use the following scripts to convert them to imagemap:

- http://code.google.com/p/svg2imap/
- http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/creating-an-image-map-from-svg/

Also if you need to mark the zones out of a plain image file, you can do it with Gimp:

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-image-map-gimp/

Or you can use a shareware windows program [MapEdit](http://www.boutell.com/mapedit/) (fully functional 30 days)

Comment: I got the coords. But  I only know add a solid surround it. But don't know change background

Comment: Check out the the first two libraries I posted, they let you add nice effects, no need to change backgrounds.